# SVN - how to apply change made in trunk to all branches

Tags: svn, merge

I am a beginner in SVN.I have the SVN directory structure like this:

```
|-trunk
  |-file1.php
  |-file2.php
|-branches
  |-branch_1
    |-file1.php
    |-file2.php
  |-branch_2
    |-file1.php
    |-file2.php
```

In the trunk I have the main version of my application. I have two branches for different clients which have the modifications only in some files. When I find some core bug I fix it in trunk. For example I modified the `file1.php` in `trunk` directory. I want to apply changes to the files named `file1.php` in all the branches.

I am little confused. In the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/index.html) I have found the following explanation.

> Subversion's repository has a special
>   design. When you copy a directory, you
>   don't need to worry about the
>   repository growing huge—Subversion
>   doesn't actually duplicate any data.
>   Instead, it creates a new directory
>   entry that points to an existing tree.

So I though that when I commit a change in the file `trunk\file1.php` it will be automaticaly aplied to the other `file1.php` files as I didn't make any changes to that files in `branches` directory.

**How can I apply changes from trunk directory to all the branches?** I was trying to use `svn merge` like this:

```
svn merge -r 31:32 http://mysvnserver.com/project/branches/branch_1
```

but I didn't do any changes (`svn diff -r 31:32` returns all the changes I made.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to apply a change from trunk to branch_1, the merge command needs to specify where to get the diff *from*, and then specify a target to apply the merge to:

```
cd branch_1
svn merge -r 31:32 http://mysvnserver.com/project/trunk .
svn diff   # confirm that the only diff is your change to file1.php
svn commit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cd workingcopy
svn merge -r 31:32 http://mysvnserver.com/project/trunk branches/branch_1
svn merge -r 31:32 http://mysvnserver.com/project/trunk branches/branch_2
svn commit -m "Merged r32 into branches"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
svn merge -r 31:32 http://mysvnserver.com/project/trunk branch_1
```

where `branch_1` is your local working directory of the branch.  That is, first you have the source address, and then the destination, which must be local.