# What is the best way to merge specific changes in several branches and trunk?

Tags: eclipse, svn, merge, branch

I used SVN/CVS for a long time just as a place where my code stored is. But now I came to a point where I need a "best way to do".

We have several branches.
For Example:

- `Release1` (shipped),
- `Release2` (not finished, contains new features),
- `Fix1` (contains bug fixes for `Release1` and will be shipped after customer tests),
- `Fix2/trunk` (The `trunk` is our current development state with `Fix2`).

And now we come to my problem.

I cannot say if `Release 2` is shipped before `Fix1` or `Fix2` and I have now a `Hotfix` for `Release1`. Just a few files, but it was urgent.

What is now the best way to get the changes in all branches?
Auto merge will also merge differences that are branch specific. Is the best way to merge it by hand?
There has to be a way like: I mark my change with ID "`abc`" and say merge only changes of `abc` in all branches.

Btw. I am using Eclipse with Subversive. Maybe a tool outside eclipse will be better!?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645409/svn-how-to-apply-change-made-in-trunk-to-all-branches can start to help

Comment: Merging from one branch to another is not the problem. The problem is that i want to merge only some changes. Consider following: you have an old version of your software and branched it into 2 branches for 2 different customers. Now you do an fix on your old version(because customer3 uses it) and you want to merge ONLY the new changes to your 2 branches because there are different features on the branches .. its difficult to describe in english :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Subclipse plugin for Eclipse.  You can probably do this with svn command line also. If your fix is isolated to a single revision number then you can merge just that revision to the trunk(or any other branch).

- branch1 (revision 103) -hotfix
- trunk (revision 100)

Using Subclipse, you can right click the file then choose "Team"->"Merge." Select either "Merge a range of revision" or "Merge two different trees" option then provide the source url and revision to merge to the target tree.

From command line... given that your current working directory is the trunk:

```
svn merge -r 103:103 http://svn/branches/branch1
```

You probably can't merge to multiple branches and that's probably better because you want to be careful with the merge process.

Comment: Oh, and you should verify the merge result than commit. Subclipse also allows you to view a simulated result of the merge process before the actual merge is done.